# Button for selection data of database from django app

Tags: python, django, database

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Home,Signup,Login,logout,Cart,Checkout,OrderView
from .middlewares import LoginCheckMiddleware,LogoutCheckMiddleware

urlpatterns = [
    path('',Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('signup',LogoutCheckMiddleware(Signup.as_view()), name='signup'),
    path('login',LogoutCheckMiddleware(Login.as_view()), name='login'),
    path('logout',LoginCheckMiddleware(logout), name='logout'),
    path('cart',Cart.as_view(), name='cart'),
    path('checkout',LoginCheckMiddleware(Checkout.as_view()), name='checkout'),
    path('order',LoginCheckMiddleware(OrderView.as_view()), name='order'),
]
```

how i can create a button from index to choose a categorie from my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are directly passing the query set in view and using it as .

You have to loop (using Django template language) through the query set in html like this:

```
<form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i> </span>
                     </div>
                <select name="start_time" id="id_start_time" class="form-control">
                      {% for each_country in name %}
                          <option value="{{each_country.name}}">{{each_country.name}}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                </select>
                </div> <!-- input-group.// -->
                </div> <!-- form-group// -->
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
```

Notice that I have added for loop using Django template tags.